# Automated Integration Testing of an API in Azure Functions using VSTS

Tags: testing, azure, azure-devops, api

I am building a HTTP API as an Azure Function App in C# and I would like to run automated integration tests (calls to the API) as part of the CI/CD.

Is this possible to do using VSTS?

I have searched but only found how to do unit testing (not integration testing) as part of the deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference on vsts for your test (unit, integrated or functional). You just set the right dll name with your tests:
[image]

or select Test plan if you have a test plan with associated test recordings
[image]